# Having difficulties fetching dynamic DB record with data-id modal attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

My overall aim is to select a reply, have that ID sent to a hidden input, then use that in my controller (which I believe I may have sussed with help elsewhere). However, I am struggling to retrieve the ID of a reply using the "data-id = {{r->id}}" attribute. Looking at the console log, it's only reporting back the first REPLY with an ID of '1' and none of the others. It is within a loop so I don't know why it is not showing the second reply unless I have to manually fetch that using a GET controller request but shouldn't have to as I can directly access the first reply. Or must I include a loop within my jquery so that the data-id changes on each loop? but surely that'd already be solved in the foreach loop above as you'll see in my source code below.

I believe this is a very basic fix but I've been pulling my hair out trying to solve it for a long time so I'd be very appreciative for some assistance.

I've had a look at this and no luck:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150999/update-database-value-with-bootstrap-modal-and-laravel-5-2
```

I added an ID to the "modals id" which prevented the same content of the first modal from existing in others due to the way this page has been programmed.

I am unsure whether my foreach loop is interferring in some way.
I haven't included my controllers and models because it's loop/JQuery issue. However, there are two models 'Ticket' & 'Reply', a Ticket has many Replies, 'slug' representing a ticket and accesses it's replies as "r".

Ticket Blade

```
@if($slug->replies->count())
                    @foreach($slug->replies as $r)
                        <div class="card message-box">
                            <div class="ticket-content">
                                {{ $r->message }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer reply-footer bg-transparent" style="height: 2.5rem">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark" id="open-modal"
                                         data-id="{{$r->id}}" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#edit-modal-{{$r->id}}">Edit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- edit reply modal !-->
                            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal-{{$r->id}}">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title">Edit</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                    aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <form id="edit-reply">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="reply-id" class="hidden-id">
                                                    <textarea class="form-control testing" id="edit-box" rows="12"
                                                              name="edit-message"
                                                              required></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark"
                                                        id="edit-button" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                        style="font-weight: bold;">Confirm
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       $('#open-modal').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id')
            $('.hidden-id').val(id);
             console.log(id)
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Every time open modal will be override in loop. So it will give you last id. Instead of this use class base modal and it should be in out of loop.

Comment: Okay but it's giving me the first id though not the last? or do you mean the last ID it can find?

Comment: You should use class instead and you can refer jQuery(this).data('id');

Comment: Okay makes sense. Must I change my button to a class too as well as my modal? beacuse the button is where the data-id is gonig to be received

Comment: Yes, You are right. You can also take only single modal and just change the content on click of button so that you will stop repeating your self.

Comment: My goodness can't believe it was that easy (though I swear I tried that out before but obviously not). Thank you very very much!

Comment: You are very welcome. Nothing is impossible. Keep doing hard work. :)